# Suppose that $A ,\ B,$ and $C$ are are $n\times n$ matrices such that $ABC=I_n$ Show that $A \, B,$ and $C$ are invertible matrices.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, proof-verification, solution-verification

Consider that $ABC=I_n \implies (ABC)^{-1}=(I_n)^{-1} \implies C^{-1}B^{-1}A^{-1}=I_n^{-1}=I_n$.

Since $ABCI_n=ABC=I_n \implies ABCC^{-1}B^{-1}A^{-1}=I_n \implies A ,\ B,$ and $C$ are invertible $n\times n$ matrices.

Q.E.D.

---

Is this the proper approach to showing the desired result?

Comment: How can you write $B^{-1}$ if you don't know that $B$ is invertible?

Comment: @Tryss I suppose you couldn't. I'm at a loss.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Be careful, you can't write $(ABC)^{-1}=C^{-1}B^{-1}A^{-1}$ until you have proved that $A$, $B$ and $C$ are invertible. It's in fact what you want to prove ! i.e. that if $ABC=I_n$ then $(ABC)^{-1}=C^{-1}B^{-1}A^{-1}$.

Since $$ABC=A(BC)=(AB)C=I_n,$$ the matrix $A$ and $C$ are invertible. Rest to prove that $B$ is also invertible.

**Hint**

Use the fact that since $A(BC)=I_n$ and $(AB)C=I_n$ then $A(BC)=(BC)A$ and $(AB)C=C(AB)$.

Answer (score 2):

You can also take determinant on both sides and observe that (i) $\det(ABC)=\det(A)\det(B)\det(C)$ and (ii) if the product of three numbers is $1$ then none of them is zero.

Comment: I don't think that the determinant is allowed.

Comment: @Surb I suspected that could be a possibility too but the OP has not explicitly stated so. Since your post covers the OP's direct concern, I address an alternative solution.

Comment: It's in fact a good idea, I just precise that it's probably not the way to solve the problem. Moreover, the OP probably doesn't know the determinant :-)